# C# difference between linq select vs lambda select

Tags: c#, linq

I have this test queries using EF db context.

```
Func<Item, ItemDto> qry = x => new ItemDto() {
  Id = x.Id,
  Name = x.Name
};
List<ItemDto> test1 = db.Items.Select(qry).ToList(); // works
List<ItemDto> test2 = (from item in db.Items select qry).ToList(); // run-time error
```

my run-time error

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Func<Progam.Item, Progam.ItemDto>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Progam.ItemDto>'
```

First is i'm not focusing on the error, rather I'd like to know the difference between Lambda-way Select and Linq-way Select [Reference to NikolaiDante's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34980144/difference-between-lambda-and-linq).

Thanks!

***Edit**

Lets say the goal is actually to have something like

```
Func<Item, ItemDto> qry = x => new ItemDto() {
      Id = x.Id,
      ItemCode = x.ItemCode
    };

var qry1 = (from p in db.Sales
            select new SaleDto() { 
                TranNo = p.TranNo
                , ExtItem = (from p1 in db.Items.Where(p2 => p2.ProductCode == p.ItemCode) 
                            select qry).FirstOrDefault()
}).ToList();

var qry2 = (from p in db.Returns
            select new ReturnDto() { 
                TranNo = p.TranNo
                , ExtItem = (from p1 in db.Items.Where(p2 => p2.ProductCode == p.ItemCode) 
                             select qry).FirstOrDefault()
}).ToList();
```

Is this doable? I'm sure i'm doing something wrong here, probably some better pattern to tackle this?

Note: What I'm also trying to do here is a one time query, and avoid using `foreach` after the query.

Comment: It is not run-time error. `select qry` -> `select qry(item)`

Comment: @PetSerAl sorry, can you please explain further?

Answer (score 1):

The `select` query operator takes an expression to evaluate, not a lambda.

Therefore, your code produces a list of lambdas.

Comment: Do you mean I should use Expression<Func rather than Func alone?

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, they both belong to the `LINQ` framework and their performance will be identical, since the compiler will turn any query syntax into method syntax at assembly generation time (though it may choose a slightly different interpretation for complex queries).

For more information, read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/query-syntax-and-method-syntax-in-linq).

There are scenarios in which lambdas can be used for anonymous methods and aren't threated as `LINQ`, like [lambda expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx).

**EDIT - QUESTION UPDATE**

```
var qry2 = (from p in db.Returns
            select new ReturnDto()
            { 
                TranNo  = p.TranNo,
                ExtItem = (from p1 in db.Items.Where(p2 => p2.ProductCode == p.ItemCode)
                           select new ItemDto()
                           {
                               Id = p1.Id,
                               ItemCode = p1.ItemCode
                           })
                           .FirstOrDefault()
            })
            .ToList();
```

or, based on your lambda expression:

```
var qry2 = (from p in db.Returns
            select new ReturnDto()
            { 
                TranNo  = p.TranNo,
                ExtItem = (from p1 in db.Items.Where(p2 => p2.ProductCode == p.ItemCode)
                           select qty(p1)).FirstOrDefault()
            })
            .ToList();
```

Comment: right, I did some edit and still trying to see if its possible to make the 'Select' re-usable for other queries.

Comment: Since your `qry` is an expression (not a lambda) you should apply it to something like `select qry(item)` as PetSerAl recommended.

Comment: so basically the short answer is not doable since i'm trying to wrap that 'Select' isn't it?

Comment: Yes, you cannod do as you wished unfortunately, you have somehow to reference the target item into your expression to apply it :) The select operator wants an expression to evaluate.

Comment: that's sad for select query operator, though I'm still wondering why .Select(qry) works.